# Merge multiple lists

Tags: haskell

Is there a way, in haskell to merge multiple lists to one list?
e.g.:

Input:

```
[
[0,2,0,4,0,6,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,3,0,0,6,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1]
]
```

Expected Output:
`[0,2,3,4,0,6,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transpose` (you may need `Data.List`) to swap lines and columns of your table to simplify the processing.

Example:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 3]]
```

becomes

```
[[0, 0],
 [1, 0],
 [0, 2],
 [2, 0],
 [3, 3]]
```

Now you have a list of old columns, so you can process them one by one. For example, you could write such a function:

```
merge list = case dropWhile (== 0) of [] -> 0
                                      (x:_) -> x
```

Here we drop all leading zeros from the list, and look if the remaining list has some value, then we take it, otherwise we get 0 as a result.

Now we can use this function to process the transposed table like this:

```
mergeLists lists = map merge (transpose lists)
```

Now, we can get rid of parentheses:

```
mergeLists lists = map merge $ transpose lists
```

Or even get rid of argument (use composition):

```
mergeLists = map merge . transpose
```

Here we say, that merging lists is 1) transposing the table and 2) processing each column with `merge`. Each of these three versions is equivalent, so you can use any of them.

Some further reading on composition: http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#composition

You can see how it works here: https://repl.it/repls/ReasonablePerfectOptimization

EDIT: fixed `merge` to use pattern matching

Comment: @WillNess yes, see the link in the upd vesion of answer, it produces the desired output

Comment: For your `let skipZeros = ... in ...`, I would prefer `case dropWhile (==0) list of [] -> 0; x:_ -> x`. See also [A Crossroad at a Branch](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/crossroad.xhtml) for more about why.